# Representing epsilon productions with FParsec parser combinators

Tags: parsing, f#, fparsec

It is often convenient to express grammar productions in BNF like

```
A ::= "car"
   |  "bike"
   |  ε
```

where ε represents an empty production rule; i.e., the nonterminal "A" could expand to the terminals "car", "bike", or nothing.  However, unless I refactor my grammar, it is unclear to me how I would represent such a grammar in FParsec.  I am aware of the 'choice' combinator, `<|>`, but as far as I know there is no 'empty' combinator.  I.e., a combinator that returns true and consumes no input.

I've searched the FParsec documentation high and low, but I have not found anything that does this, which surprises me, because this seems like a common scenario.  I'm fairly new to FParsec (and combinators in general), so maybe I am just not using the right words.  Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Jack's solution should do the trick for you. However, if you're looking for a primitive that represents a parser which succeeds, without consuming any input, then you probably want `preturn` from `FParsec.Primitives` (see [`preturn` in the documentation](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/primitives.html#members.preturn)).

It could be useful if you were combining parsers that build values of some AST instead of strings. For example if you had a discriminated union:

```
type Vehicle = Car | Bike | Other
```

You could use `pstring "car" >>% Car` and `pstring "bike" >>% Bike` to build parsers that return `Vehicle` values. Then you could combine them using `<|>` and add a special (empty) case using `preturn`:

```
let parseA = 
  pstring "car" >>% Car <|> 
  pstring "bike" >>% Bike <|>
  preturn Other
```

The `preturn` operation is probably not used directly very often, but it is one of the basic primitives (because it defines the monadic *unit* or *return* operation of parsers).

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this, Tomas.  Indeed, I subsequently found and used `preturn` after posting the above question.

Comment: I just noticed [this](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/primitives.html#members.:60::124::62::37:) in the fparsec docs -- you can optimize the `<|> preturn Other` as `<|>% Other`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with FParsec -- I usually use fsyacc -- but what happens if you use an empty string with the choice combinator? E.g., something like:

```
let parseA = pstring "car" <|> pstring "bike" <|> pstring ""
```

Comment: Duh.  This is a case of having overthought the problem.  Thanks.